# MariaDB 10.0.7 upgrade from 10.0.6 dependency problems package is not configured yet

Tags: dependencies, package, mariadb, apt-get

Running Debian Wheezy on kernel 3.12.5 with MariaDB 10.0.6.  Performed an apt-get update and apt-get upgrade, and ran into an issue:

```
root@zeus:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl gnupg gpgv libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 libpixman-1-0 mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common
  mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0 megactl megaraid-status mysql-common virtualbox-4.3
18 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 110 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,697 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
Get:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ wheezy/contrib virtualbox-4.3 amd64 4.3.6-91406~Debian~wheezy [69.7 MB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main curl amd64 7.26.0-1+wheezy7 [269 kB]
Get:3 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mariadb-server all 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [3,002 B]
Get:4 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mysql-common all 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [8,844 B]
Get:5 http://hwraid.le-vert.net/debian/ wheezy/main megactl amd64 0.4.1+svn20090725.r6-2 [60.8 kB]
Get:6 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mariadb-common all 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [3,306 B]
Get:7 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main libmariadbclient18 amd64 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [941 kB]
Get:8 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libcurl3 amd64 7.26.0-1+wheezy7 [330 kB]
Get:9 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.26.0-1+wheezy7 [321 kB]
Get:10 http://hwraid.le-vert.net/debian/ wheezy/main megaraid-status all 0.11 [7,626 B]
Get:11 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main libpixman-1-0 amd64 0.26.0-4+deb7u1 [427 kB]
Get:12 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main libmysqlclient18 amd64 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [2,964 B]
Get:13 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mariadb-client-core-10.0 amd64 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [1,993 kB]
Get:14 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main gpgv amd64 1.4.12-7+deb7u3 [227 kB]
Get:15 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main gnupg amd64 1.4.12-7+deb7u3 [1,953 kB]
Get:16 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mariadb-client-10.0 amd64 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [5,592 kB]
Get:17 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mariadb-server-core-10.0 amd64 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [6,077 kB]
Get:18 http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian/ wheezy/main mariadb-server-10.0 amd64 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy [22.3 MB]
Fetched 110 MB in 26s (4,087 kB/s)
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 86984 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace curl 7.26.0-1+wheezy6 (using .../curl_7.26.0-1+wheezy7_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement curl ...
Preparing to replace libcurl3:amd64 7.26.0-1+wheezy6 (using .../libcurl3_7.26.0-1+wheezy7_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libcurl3:amd64 ...
Preparing to replace libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 7.26.0-1+wheezy6 (using .../libcurl3-gnutls_7.26.0-1+wheezy7_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 ...
Preparing to replace libpixman-1-0:amd64 0.26.0-4 (using .../libpixman-1-0_0.26.0-4+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libpixman-1-0:amd64 ...
Preparing to replace mariadb-server 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mariadb-server_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mariadb-server ...
Preparing to replace mysql-common 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mysql-common_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql-common ...
Preparing to replace mariadb-common 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mariadb-common_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mariadb-common ...
Preparing to replace libmariadbclient18 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../libmariadbclient18_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmariadbclient18 ...
Preparing to replace libmysqlclient18 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../libmysqlclient18_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libmysqlclient18 ...
Preparing to replace mariadb-client-core-10.0 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mariadb-client-core-10.0 ...
Preparing to replace mariadb-client-10.0 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mariadb-client-10.0 ...
Preparing to replace mariadb-server-core-10.0 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mariadb-server-core-10.0 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mysql-common (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-common (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
(Reading database ... 86984 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mariadb-server-10.0 10.0.6+maria-1~wheezy (using .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
Unpacking replacement mariadb-server-10.0 ...
Preparing to replace virtualbox-4.3 4.3.4-91027~Debian~wheezy (using .../virtualbox-4.3_4.3.6-91406~Debian~wheezy_amd64.deb) ...
Stopping VirtualBox web service ...done.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
dpkg: ... it looks like that went OK
Unpacking replacement virtualbox-4.3 ...
Preparing to replace gpgv 1.4.12-7+deb7u2 (using .../gpgv_1.4.12-7+deb7u3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gpgv ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Setting up gpgv (1.4.12-7+deb7u3) ...
(Reading database ... 86987 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace gnupg 1.4.12-7+deb7u2 (using .../gnupg_1.4.12-7+deb7u3_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gnupg ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Setting up gnupg (1.4.12-7+deb7u3) ...
(Reading database ... 86987 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace megactl 0.4.1+svn20090725.r6-1 (using .../megactl_0.4.1+svn20090725.r6-2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement megactl ...
Preparing to replace megaraid-status 0.10 (using .../megaraid-status_0.11_all.deb) ...
[ ok ] Stopping megaraidsas-status monitor: megaraidsas-statusd.
Unpacking replacement megaraid-status ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libcurl3:amd64 (7.26.0-1+wheezy7) ...
Setting up curl (7.26.0-1+wheezy7) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.26.0-1+wheezy7) ...
Setting up libpixman-1-0:amd64 (0.26.0-4+deb7u1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-4.3 (4.3.6-91406~Debian~wheezy) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/vboxdrv ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modulesError! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
 ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module ...done.
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Starting VirtualBox VMs configured for autostartls: cannot access /home/vbox/vboxdb/*.start: No such file or directory
Starting VirtualBox web service ...done.
Setting up megactl (0.4.1+svn20090725.r6-2) ...
Setting up megaraid-status (0.11) ...
[ ok ] Starting megaraidsas-status monitor: megaraidsas-statusd.
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up libmariadbclient18 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-core-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
dpkg: error processing mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The key portion being:

```
Setting up libmysqlclient18 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up libmariadbclient18 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-core-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-client-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
dpkg: error processing mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I then tried:

```
root@zeus:~# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
dpkg: error processing mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And then tried

```
root@zeus:~# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
dpkg: error processing mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (= 10.0.7+maria-1~wheezy); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.0
 mariadb-server
```

I restarted the service and found that it would start without error (surprising).  I then also found that the upgrade seemed to have taken place, as I am running 10.0.7 now:

```
root@zeus:~# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 38
Server version: 10.0.7-MariaDB-1~wheezy mariadb.org binary distribution
```

I am looking for assistance in resolving the apt errors without losing my configuration or having to delete anything as this machine is in production.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when trying to upgrade from MariaDB 5.5.34 to 10.0.10 - uninstalling und reinstalling did not help. But running

`apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*`

did it, it removed all packages with mysql and mariadb context (and the mysql directories) and it seems as if one of these packages was somehow responsible for the botched installation attempts.

Afterwards I ran `aptitude install mariadb-server` and it worked without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Unfortunately I can really only equate my solution to "violently screaming while trying everything and anything until it worked".  That said, maybe I can provide some insight.

Here are the recent commands I ran, which is everything from when I realized it was broken until I fixed it:

```
 9952  sudo service mysql status
 9953  sudo service mysql stoy
 9954  sudo service mysql stop
 9955  sudo apt-get update
 9956  sudo apt-get upgrade
 9957  dconf-editor
 9958  dconf-editor --help
 9959  dconf-editor
 9960  sudo apt-get upgrade
 9961  sudo apt-get install -f
 9962  dpkg --configure -a
 9963  sudo dpkg --configure -a
 9964  sudo service mysql restart
 9965  sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*' 'mariadb*'
 9966  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.0
 9967  sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*' 'mariadb*'
 9968  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
 9969  sudo apt-get install -f
 9970  sudo dpkg --configure -a
 9971  mysql
 9972  sudo service mysql restart
 9973  sudo service mysql start
 9974  mysql
 9975  l /var/run/mysqld
 9976  sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 9977  l /var/run/mysqld
 9978  sudo chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld
 9979  l /var/run/mysqld
 9980  mysql
 9981  sudo rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 9982  mysql
 9983  sudo dpkg --configure -a
 9984  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.0.6+maria-1~raring
 9985  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.0.6+maria
 9986  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.0.6
 9987  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.0.6+maria-1'raring
 9988  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.0.6+maria-1-raring
 9989  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server=10.0.6+maria-1
 9990  apt-cache madison mariadb-server
 9991  sudo apt-get install devscripts
 9992  rmadison
 9993  rmadison mariadb-server
 9994  rmadison sude
 9995  rmadison sudo
 9996  rmadison mariadb-server
 9997  apt-show-versions
 9998  _apt-show-versions
 9999  _apt-show-versions -h
10000  sudo apt-get install apt-show-versions
10001  apt-show-versions sudo
10002  apt-show-versions mysql
10003  apt-show-versions mariadb-server
10004  apt-show-versions -p mariadb-server
10005  apt-show-versions -a mariadb-server
10006  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
10007  mysql
10008  sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*' 'mariadb*'
10009  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
10010  apt-show-versions mysql-server
10011  apt-show-versions -a mysql-server
10012  rmadison mysql-server
10013  sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*' 'mariadb*'
10014  sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.5.32-0ubuntu7
10015  sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.5.29-0ubuntu1
10016  sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*' 'mariadb*'
10017  rmadison mysql-server
10018  sudo apt-get install mysql-server
10019  sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
10020  find / -name '*.sock'
10021  sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*' 'mariadb*'
10022  sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
10023  mysql
```

There is a lot of useless and needless stuff in there but I'm not 100% sure what the solution was.  That said, there are two things that stick out:

1. `sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag`
2. The fact that I tried installing normal mysql (which also failed), and then tried mariadb again after purging them.

Both of these things happened near the end of the above history excerpt, and again I only included the entire log in case it was something else.

Answer (score 0):

The same dependency problem occurs with 10.0.13 (released 11th August 2014)

Trying a clean install of the metapackage with apt or aptitude both fail. So does trying `apt-get install mariadb-server-10.0` Removing the version flag doesnt fix anything either

To fix it I installed 10.1

(assuming you are already running mariadb in a chroot)

```
cp -rf /etc/mysql /etc/mysql.bak
apt-get remove --purge mariadb*
mv /etc/mysql.bak /etc/mysql
```

point `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `/10.1/`

```
apt-get update && apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Subsequently trying to downgrade to `10.0` does not work - `10.1` runs without issue.